# Clicking in an inactive window with ctypes

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I need to send a message to an inactive window that my mouse clicked using ctypes. I'm trying to do this via SendMessageA, but nothing happens. I define the hwnd and open another window on top of this one, then it should just click in the initial window. How do I do this?

```
hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
time.sleep(10)
ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(hwnd,  0x0201, 0, 0)
ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(hwnd,  0x0202, 0, 0)
```

Comment: SendMessage does not care if the window is active. What is 0x0201?

Comment: @Anders 0x0201 - press left mouse button, 0x0202 - release left mouse button. Do you know any other ways in python to pass a click to an inactive window?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the active window by sending a message.

Call [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) to change the active window.